# Targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

When I create a new Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio 2017, in the project properties I can't target any other framework than

- .NET standard 1.0
- .NET standard 1.1
- .NET standard 1.2
- .NET standard 1.3
- .NET standard 1.4
- .NET standard 1.5
- .NET standard 1.6
- .NET standard 2.0

I'm trying to use a nuget package targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 and it doesn't load because of that.
I have a warning when i add that package :

`The package CHU.Xamarin.Helpers 1.0.0.1 has been restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of target framework of the project '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. The package might not be totally compatible with your project.`

Is there a way to target .NET Framework 4.6.1 in the project ?

If i add the nuget package anyway, i've got an error saying it is not compatible with monoandroid71 :

`The package CHU.Xamarin.Helpers 1.0.0.1 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). The package CHU.Xamarin.Helpers 1.0.0.1 handles : net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)`

The error messages are translated from French so might differs from english counterpart

Comment: .net core and .net frameworks can't be mixed in the same project

Comment: What you can do is add a .NET PCL that targets the framework you need to your project and use that instead of the .NET Standard one.

Comment: Which package you want to use? Because new version of Xamarin supports only .net Standard versions.

Comment: Correct answer by Jeremy Thompson.

Comment: @JeremyThompson That's incorrect. 

You can mix .net core and .net frameworks.

Comment: @imps you cant just say that without giving an example... show me a .Net Core project with Full Framework (Windows OS specific) code  running on Linux?

Comment: @JeremyThompson
My bad for misreading his comment. 
You're correct that he can't mix them in this case. 

However, I disagree with the blanket statement.

That compatibility check is there for a reason.
There is a potential surface API level compatibility between the 2, which is why NuGet installs it with a warning.

Comment: Who gave you the package CHU.Xamarin.Helpers? Its authors should make it compatible to Xamarin projects (various target platforms, but none of them is `net461`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: None of the following answers "how to target .NET **Framework** 4.6.1 for a Xamarin.Forms project". If you really, truly, need to know how to do that, and know what you are doing, and why, then search elsewhere - doing so is an advanced topic, and is no longer recommended. For cross-platform projects, stick with a .NET **Standard** version.

In this case, despite the question title, doing so is **not** the solution. Keep reading for more details.

---

> I'm trying to use a nuget package targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 and it doesn't load because of that.

Actually, it does load. It gives you a warning. You can probably ignore that **Framework** vs **Standard** warning - I've been ignoring a Framework 4.6.1 vs Standard 2.0 warning for over a year, without problem.

> error .. saying it is not compatible with monoandroid71

This is the real problem that is stopping you.
Is there a `packages.config` file? If so, open it in a text editor, and search for `monoandroid71`. If present, then yes, this is the problem -
The packages.config mechanism contains an outdated "hint", OR you ARE targeting an older Android version, that is not compatible with the nuget you wish to use - as the message says.

Possible fix:

- Target Android 8.0 or higher. In your Android project (e.g. if you named your Xamarin Forms project "App1", look in solution for the project labeled "App1.Android") / Properties / Application / Compile using Android version (Target Framework) / select Oreo or Pie.
- Update all nugets to latest.
- If packages.config still mentions monoandroid71, then you have outdated "hints".

Different ways to fix outdated hints in project.config. Do ONE of the following:

- Rt-click on project.config in Solution pane, select "Migrate to PackageReferences". This newer mechanism doesn't rely on hints.
- OR Delete project.config. Add the nugets again.
- OR Manually edit project.config. Change all targetframework=monoandroidXX to be the same - whatever the highest number you find in the file. Probably monoandroid81 or monoandroid90.
- OR Start all over. Latest VS 2017 version OR VS 2019. Either works fine for this purpose. New project / C# / Mobile App Xamarin Forms. Copy your source files (.cs, .xaml) to the new projects - DON'T use your old .csproj or package.config. The goal is to use all the latest build options, including PackageReferences.